# How to show spinner or loading on the screen completely

Tags: css, angular, sass

Im from Mobile background. In Android applications we do show a spinner dialog to avoid user interaction while there is a network activity. I believe we can do the same using css, with the following css I can see the spinner on the screen, but I want to avoid any user interaction on the screen while showing the spinner.

```
.spinner {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    overflow: show;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following layout in HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay__wrapper">
        <div class="overlay__spinner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the overlay, set it to:

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

Inside, have a wrapper so that you can center the spinner.

```
.overlay__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Then for the spinner, add this CSS:

```
.overlay__spinner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Add your spinner-code inside `.overlay__spinner`. This will result in a semi-transparent overlay with a centered spinner in it.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly, but only problem. I'm able to see the progress bar. But the buttons are still active, when I hover the buttons are responding and Im able to click the links on the page below the progress bar.

Comment: What progress bar are you talking about? What buttons? Please specify the problem.

Comment: Please check the edited question, I have uploaded a picture. I could get the spinner while the button below the spinner is active and clickable. Basically I want to avoid any user interaction while there is some network activity or something

Comment: Add z-index: 9999; to the .overlay CSS